# Quitting out of Bash with Putty

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

I'm trying to ssh into the server.  I enter my password (which is accepted) and then it takes me into this:

```
using username "####".
##hostname## password: ##This is correct
Last lgin: Sun Feb 10 11:47:27 2013 from ####
-bash-3.2$
```

How do I quit out of bash?  I've tried logout and exit and both of them quit out of Putty.  When I open Putty again and login it takes me right to -bash-3.2$ again.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen? When you quit bash, your session is done.

Comment: I want to got to files in my directory

Comment: You need a shell for that. That's what bash is. Learn to use it. (Once you quit your first shell (bash here), your connection is closed. You're disconnected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seing is the prompt, meaning the way the server let's you interconnect with it.

If you want to "navigate" through the server, you will have to use commands like `cd` (change directory), `ls` (list), `cp` (copy) and so on. Try for example to type `pwd` and you will see the current directory in which you are (pwd stands for print working directory).

There are millions of tutorials of this, google it to find someone. I for example found this one: http://www.gamexe.net/other/beginner-guide-ssh/